# I cannot log into minecraft technic launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to log into technic launcher but for some reason it wont let me.

I have reset my password and username but it still says that the info I'm using is an invalid credential.

I have tried old usernames and passwords.

I know I'm using the right info because I have reset my name and password to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mojang has a support article on their website that explains possible reasons you might not be able to log in:

https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/329527-minecraft-log-in

> **Do I log in with my email address or my username?**
>
> There are two
> account types - Minecraft accounts and Mojang accounts.
>
> Any Minecraft account created after Fall 2012, or one that has been
> migrated from the old account format is located on a Mojang account,
> and logs in with its email address. An older Minecraft account that
> has not yet been migrated uses the username to login.
>
> You can learn more about the different account types here
>
> **I forgot my password**
>
> To reset the password for a Minecraft account
> (you log in with your username) visit account.mojang.com/migrate.
>
> To reset the password for a Mojang account (you log in with your email
> address) visit account.mojang.com/password.
>
> **I forgot the email address used for my account**
>
> If you have a Mojang
> account and have forgotten the email that you log in with, try
> resetting your password. This will send an email to the address that
> you have registered, letting you know which address you used.
> Alternatively,  try other email addresses that you own.  If you cannot
> get Mojang system emails, visit this article
>
> **I need to change the email address used for my account**
>
> If you have a
> Minecraft account you will need to migrate it to change the email
> address, to learn more please go here.
>
> To change the email on a Mojang account, visit
> account.mojang.com/me/settings. You can either have instructions sent
> to your current address or, if you don't have access to that email,
> you can have it changed by passing a security challenge.
>
> **I remember my email address, but not my username.**
>
> If you have a
> Mojang account, your Minecraft username will be shown in-game and on
> your Mojang account page.
>
> **I've tried the above, but I still need help.**
>
> Please contact customer
> support through the contact form.

For clickable links, visit the article support page linked above.

Answer (score 0):

If you've migrated to a Mojang account, or made an account since mid-2012, then you need to use your email instead of your username to login.